# Different colors for itemize in blocks and outside, in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, color

I would like to obtain what I describe in the following MWE, that is the `itemize` symbol should be

- black outside blocks;
- blue in *normal* blocks;
- red in alert blocks;
- green in example blocks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Here in blue, I'd like it in black. 
\end{itemize}
\begin{block}{A block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in blue, I'd like keep it in blue. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{alertblock}{An alert block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in red, I'd like keep it in red. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\begin{exampleblock}{An example block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in green, I'd like keep it in green. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Minimum working example]

If I look to `beamercolorthemedefault.sty`, I see that `item`s are colored using the `local structure` color:

- If I change the `local structure` to black, *normal* blocks become black;
- If I change directly the `item` color to black, it is black in all blocks.

So what is the correct way to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would set the colour of `local structure` to black for normal text, then change it to match the colour of `structure` again when you start a normal block. This can be done by adding the redefinition of the colour to the beamer template`block begin`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=normal text}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=structure}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Here in blue, I'd like it in black. 
\end{itemize}
\begin{block}{A block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in blue, I'd like keep it in blue. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{alertblock}{An alert block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in red, I'd like keep it in red. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\begin{exampleblock}{An example block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in green, I'd like keep it in green. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the example code with bullets coloured in black, blue, red and green]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

One possibility is to set the `itemize item` color to black. This will affect *all* of the `itemize` environments, but then with the help of the `etoolbox` package you can restore the desired colors inside the blocks:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}
\AtBeginEnvironment{block}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=structure}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alertblock}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=block title alerted.fg}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exampleblock}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=block title example.fg}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}
\AtBeginEnvironment{block}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=structure}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alertblock}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=block title alerted.fg}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exampleblock}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=block title example.fg}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Here in black, as desired. 
\end{itemize}
\begin{block}{A block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in blue, I'd like keep it in blue. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{alertblock}{An alert block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in red, I'd like keep it in red. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\begin{exampleblock}{An example block}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item Here in green, I'd like keep it in green. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I choose to accept the other answer since it is simpler.